# Remove contant of a previous page when next load in collection view in paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pagination, uicollectionview

I am using a `UICollectionView` with paging feature and adding `AVPlayer` on each cell to play video with `URL`, but my collection view is giving a strange behavior.  When it loads the first cell and video starts playing then it is fine but when I slide and load the next cell then both videos are playing together, while I want the previous one to stop playing. I tried many thing to resolve this issue but nothing is working, someone please suggest me something to work with this. My code of custom cell class where I am adding `AVPlayer` is given below:

```
[self.avPlayer pause];
self.avPlayer = nil;
[self.avLPlayer removeFromSuperlayer];

CGRect videoRect;
videoRect = CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[indicator startAnimating];
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:_viewForShowVideo];
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(currentWindow.frame.size.width/2, _viewForShowVideo.frame.size.height/2, 20, 20);
[_viewForShowVideo addSubview:indicator];


self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:Url];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
self.avLPlayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];

[_avLPlayer setFrame:videoRect];
[_avLPlayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor] ;
[_avLPlayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];

_avLPlayer.opacity = 1;

_avPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
[_avPlayer setMuted:NO];
_avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;


[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];


[_viewForShowVideo.layer addSublayer:_avLPlayer];
[_avPlayer play];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnPlayer:)];
[_viewForShowVideo addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[_viewForShowVideo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: Can you please show cellForItem code method?

Comment: StoryEditingCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StoryEditingFirstCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.mediaUrl = [[arrForMediaData objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] valueForKeyPath:@"VideoUrl"];
[cell setDataOnCollectionCell_mediaType:2 mediaURL:[[arrForMediaData objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] valueForKeyPath:@"VideoUrl"] screenOrientation:@"" cellIndex:indexPath.item];
self.avPlayerOnCell = cell.avPlayer;

Comment: setDataOnCollectionCell_mediaType is a method which is implemented in custom cell class and the code of this method is given above with post.